# Synchronize after extended data type changes

Tags: database-design, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm 100% new to Dynamics Ax and am going through the training material.  It is having me create new Extended Data Types.  In the past 2 hours I have been able to create 2 because each time I create one and save it takes 30min - 1 hour to "Synchronize Table".

This is over VirtualBox.  This is VM A with 6 CPU's 12gb of ram and I have it on a SSD.

The training is telling me to save but maybe I shouldn't be saving after small changes?  It looks like it has to go through the entire database to synchronize everything.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to synchronize each time you touch EDT.

Only synchronize tables using this EDT (or child EDTs) - manually.
If you don't know all the tables, then you have to re-synchronize full database.

Synchronize is technicality required only when database related properties (string size, array) are changed. If you change label or help text then you don't have to synchronize database.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the synchronization to complete so I can't look in detail, but I just clicked the save button I didn't see any other option.  Once it's done I can see if I just clicked on the wrong thing to save.  I was adding Extended Datatypes

Comment: You can kill the AX client. You should see AX prompt asking you if you want to synchronize - just say *No*

Comment: At least it now prompts. In old times, when things were simpler, a synchronize was initiated immediately after change, but then took only 2 minutes.